# Clustered environment on Websphere asking me to make the application module "Serializable at runtime", how to fix it?

Tags: multithreading, jsf, runtime, websphere, cluster-computing

My JSF application is perfectly fine in Development environment which is non clustered Websphere server environment.

But once I deploy it on a clustered environment , I keep getting this error. I'm not sure why.
What change is it recommending?

```
00000031 WASSession    E SessionContextMBeanAdapter findAttCausingNotSerializableException 
Miscellaneous data: Attribute "searchParty" is declared to be serializable but is
found to generate exception "java.io.NotSerializableException" with message
"org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.FeatureMapUtil$FeatureEList".  
Fix the application so that the attribute "searchParty" is correctly 
serializable at runtime.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error says that in the `HttpSession` you store object that is not serializable. In your case it is `searchParty` item contains some filed of type `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.FeatureMapUtil`, which is not serializable.

Error is most probably generated by PMI counter `session size` - see the following technote [Getting java.io.NotSerializableException when SessionObjectSize counter is enabled](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21268440)

You have two solutions:

- if you plan to use persistent sessions, and replication across the cluster, code needs to be fixed to be serializable (change that field or make it `transient`)
- if you will not use persistent sessions you may disable session size counter in the PMI to get rid of that error.